# Converting from byte[ ] to user defined type

Tags: java, serialization, type-conversion

I am working on a network simulator designed in java with the basic function of routing messages through a network. I am trying to take a Message object, encrypt it using an encryption utility that gives output as byte  [ ] and then need it to continue performing the routing function through the network. The routing part makes use of a host of pre-defined methods that take Message type as argument. The problem I am facing is converting back from byte [ ] output to this Message type. I tried a couple of things.

First I tried to serialize the object, encrypt it and then tried to de-serialize the output and cast it into type Message. It did not work as it gave invalid stream header.

Secondly I tried to create a sub class EncryptedMessage that extended Message. I tried to cast the output of the encryption utility as type EncryptedMessage also did not work- gave the same error.  I have understood that while serializing this cannot be done.

I declared a variable data of type byte[ ] in EncryptedMessage and tried to assign the byte[ ] output to this but it also did not work as I eventually needed to get the output as Message only.

Is there a simple way to convert this byte[ ] output back to type Message so that it can be used further for calling all the methods functions etc.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3736247/2478821) on SO.

Comment: @ Benjamin Todts. Thanks. My requirement is different from the answer posted in the link. I need to modify the object stream by encrypting before converting back to object stream. I don't think it can be done through serialization. I need to use some other method to convert from byte [ ] to the type Message.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on how your encryption method works.  There is a [well-known way to serialize and deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736058/java-object-to-byte-and-byte-to-object-converter-for-tokyo-cabinet/3736247#3736247) a class instance in java to its byte form, however you shouldn't mistake this for encryption.  Encryption would be an operation to be performed on the byte array itself to transform it into something difficult to reverse without a proper key of some sort.  In this case, retrieving the original message is simply a matter of reversing the encryption and then reinterpreting the bytes as its original class instance.

Now if you are *hashing* Message into a byte array, you'll find you'll never be able to retrieve the original message.  This is done intentionally, and in fact it isn't meant to encrypt, but rather to check the validity of sensitive data without having to necessarily keep that sensitive data in memory.  For example if you wanted to make sure an entered password is correct, you could hash the password and check it with other hashed passwords on your database.  You can know if the password is correct without having to save the passwords on the database.

Otherwise, I would expect you to have an encryption method (AES, TKIP, WPA2 for instance) and that encryption method would most likely require some sort of input from you.  This is a private key and when you decrypt the bytes, you'd need to provide this same private key in order to retrieve the original value.  You should consider the additional complication that in Java, you can't create an instance of a type that isn't in classpath, so you would likely need to provide the class name or interface as well.

The more sophisticated encryption method is [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) in which both ends have a public and private key.  Combining their public key and your private key gives you the shared secret key required to encrypt and decrypt to and from byte arrays.  However like the above method, you would also need to provide Message class or interface in order to decrypt, meaning both parties need to have Message in classpath.

Comment: @ Neil. Thanks for the input. I am using ECC(Elliptic Curve Cryptography) and the encryption/decryption utility is not the problem.I want to route the encrypted message through the network and decrypt it at intended destination. Marrying the ECC utility with the routing functionality of the simulator which uses type Message is the issue. I need to convert from the byte[ ] output of the encryption utility, convert it to a type that can be used by the functions that use Message type as arguments and then route the encrypted message to destination where it will be decrypted by the ECC utility.

Comment: @Hashtag Could you explain it more clearly in your answer?  I'm not familiar with the ECC, but if the problem isn't directly related to usage, I can probably help you.

Comment: @ Neil. I need to encrypt the messages before routing them through the network in the simulator. The encryption utility just provides functions for encryption/decryption. However, the input and output of the encryption utility are of the type byte[ ]. The object that I need to encrypt at source and decrypt at destination is of type Message. So I need to do this conversion from object to byte[ ], encrypt it and then convert to type Message at the source before sending it through the network because the network accepts only objects of the type Message. I hope I am more clear this time.

Comment: @Hashtag Then you should decrypt the bytes, then use those bytes to create the object.  If the encryption process isn't lossy and if Message is in classpath at the destination (same version), then you should be able to reconstruct Message on the other side.  So either there is another factor at play, or one of these two conditions is not met.